# Acceptance Test Driven development of a service with several clients

Tags: testing, tdd, bdd, acceptance-testing, atdd

I have a question related to acceptance test driven development (ATDD). My application is developed as a REST Service which might have several clients - web site, mobile, desktop. The ATDD concept says that I should start every feature with an end-to-end test. Since my service might have several client applications (ends) providing the same use-cases, what approach should I use when writing the acceptance tests? Should the acceptance test take as input the direct request to REST service or the client app? Or both? I understand that if my acceptance tests start from REST request, I'm omitting the client part, which is definitely not ok. If these start from client, I will repeat basically the same functional tests for every client. I need to find an approach that stays somewhere in the middle of these edges.

Comment: "ATDD concept says that I should start every feature with an end-to-end test". I don't agree that is required. What's your source?

Answer (score 1):

As @bcarlso suggests, you can write acceptance tests in terms of the business rules, so they're not specific to one particular platform.

Using these specifications to test each sceario, end-to-end, across each platform is certainly possible, and many organisations do this. But your likely to end with a very large, slow test suite, which will difficult to maintain.

Cucumber and similar tools ATDD don't mandate that you test end-to-end. You can use them to verify behaviour in something as focused as a single method in one class.

Focus yours efforts writing good unit tests that will catch the vast majority of defects before integration. Don't rely on automated acceptance tests to be the QA for a poor development process. Use a small number of high-level end-to-end tests to test the main success paths through the app.

There is a trade-off here: Some integration-related issues may slip through the net. Perform root cause analysis and try to determine how can you avoid similar defects in future. Add additional tests at the appropriate level. Just don't let your project drown in its own test suite.

Answer (score 0):

When practicing ATDD, I consider the acceptance tests just another user interface. With that being said, I would test below the UI at the business layer. Assuming I have a feature:

```
Given I have an addend of 5
and an augend of 3
When I calculate the sum
Then I should receive 8
```

When implementing this test, my seam would be at the business layer. Assuming a Java/Spring type application my test would look something like:

```
@Given("I have an addend of (\\d+)")
public void addend(int addend) { this.addend = addend; }

@Given("I have an augend of (\\d+)")
public void augend(int augend) { this.augend = augend; }

@When("I calculate the sum")
public void calculate() {
    calculator = applicationContext.getBean(ScientificCalculator.class);
    actualResult = calculator.sum(addend, augend);
}

@Then("I should receive (\\d+)")
public void verifyResult(int result) { assertEquals(result, this.actualResult); }
```

Once I've developed the business logic behind the `ScientificCalculator` and all of the test scenarios pass, I know that the application does what it needs to do from a functional perspective. Because this completely bypasses the UI, there is no need to duplicate the tests for each UI. The UI now becomes completely void of business rules (a good thing) and you can put an XML, JSON, HTML, whatever UI you want on the front. Assuming we were using Spring MVC, the controller would be as simple as something like:

```
@GET("calculate/sum/{addend}/{augend}")
public void addSomeNumbers(String addend, String augend) {
    result = calculator.sum(Integer.parseInt(addend), Integer.parseInt(augend));
    // Render the view with the result.
}
```

Would I test the UI at all? Probably. But not nearly as thoroughly because the primary business rules are covered by the existing tests and, generally speaking, UI bugs are a bit lower risk and easier to fix than misunderstood or mis-implemented business logic.

Hope that helps!

Brandon